# Gtk label not updated in timer script

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I'm working on my first Python and GTK script. I'm trying to do a counter/timer. The problem I have is that, while the logging function returns the proper values every second, the `gtk.label` is  not updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
def startTimer(self, buttonStart):
    self.imgTimer.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_YES, 2)
    self.runTimer(120)

def runTimer(self, timeout):

    for i in reversed(range(0,timeout)):

        logging.debug(i) #returns values 
        self.labelTimer.set_text(i) #doesn't do anything

        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give GTK+ a chance to draw the updated the label.  You should either use threads (see [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.001.htp)), or something like

```
while gtk.events_pending ():
    gtk.main_iteration ()
```

after updating the label.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you. I have to study the subject because I don't really understand the idea behind it.